# Bulk import of graph data with ArangoDB java driver

Tags: arangodb

I have a question regarding bulk import when working with a graph layer of ArangoDB and its [java driver](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver). I'm using Arango 3.4.5 with java driver 5.0.0.

In a document layer, it's possible to use [ArangoCollection.importDocuments](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/java-reference-collection-bulk-import.html) to insert several documents at once. However, for the collections of the graph layer, the `ArangoEdgeCollection` and the `ArangoVertexCollection`, the `importDocuments` function (or a corresponding `importVertices`/`importEdges` function) does not exist. So, if I want to pursue a bulk import of my graph data, I have to ignore the graph layer and use the `importDocuments` function on vertex collections, `*_ELEMENT-PROPERTIES`, `*_ELEMENT-HAS-PROPERTIES`, and edge collections separately by myself.

Furthermore, when the edge collections already exist in the database, it's even not possible to perform a bulk import, because the existing collection is already defined as an edge collection.

Or maybe it's not true what I'm writing and I overlooked something essential?

If not, is there a reason why the bulk import is not implemented for the graph layer? Or is a graph bulk import just among items of a nice-to-have list which hasn't been implemented yet?

Based on my findings described above, the bulk import of graph data with java driver is IMO not possible if the graph collections already exist (because of the edge collections) (?). It would be possible to carry out the bulk import only if we created edge collections from scratch as ordinary collections, which, however, already smells of necessity to sequentially write my own basic graph layer (which I don't want to do, of course).

I guess another way is then the import of JSON data which I haven't analyzed much so far because it seems to me inconvenient when I need to manipulate (or create) the data with java before storing them. Therefore, I would really like to work with the java driver.

Thank you very much for any reply, opinion or corrections.

Comment: In ArangoDB, there really is no difference between a regular collection and a graph collection. As such you could just bulk load data into any collection independent of wether you are planning to use it as plain documents or as part of graphs traversals into new or existing collections.  So is your question about having to create the edge tables manually?

Comment: Well, there is a difference from what I've found in the Java driver. The `ArangoCollection` class contains the `importDocuments` method while the `ArangoEdgeCollection` and the `ArangoVertexCollection` classes are not subclasses of the `ArangoCollection` and do not have their own "`importDocuments`" methods. So I have to perform the bulk import of the edges into an `ArangoCollection` and if there already exist an edge collection (`ArangoEdgeCollection`), I cannot pursue a bulk import into it. Is that correct?

Comment: Frankly I have not used the java version, but that is just an implementation of  http Arango import (https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/http/bulk-imports.html). Thus, it should import data to any existing collection, independently of the collection type (there is an example in the Arango doc above to import a Json document to an edge collection). Given that there is no real difference in the way data is stored internally in edge vs vertex collections, there is no real need to have 2 imports. Are you hitting an error when trying to import edge data? Have you tried using the http api directly?